# Freeze asp.net grid view column

Tags: asp.net, gridview, freeze, auto-generate

How can i freeze initial 2 -3 leftmost column in asp.net grid view? so that while horizontal scrolling initial 2 - 3 columns that got freezes will always be display.

Any answers??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be possible with some css magic, with the pinned and scrollable columns on different z-indexes to keep the pinned on top. This comes with the caveat that `overflow:scroll` may not be 100% portable (I've tested on IE 8/9 and Chrome FWIW).

Take a look at this [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7fuQm/3/)

The ASPX I used to generate the `GridView` is below.

Note the css classes `pinned` and `scrollable` for fixed and scrolling columns respectively (applied to headers and items)

But the real work is done in the css. Note especially that you need to fiddle to get your column widths correct to align the fixed td's / th's at the left.

**aspx**

```
<div id="scrolledGridView">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Col 1">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="pinned col1"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="pinned col1"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Column 2">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="pinned col2"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="pinned col2"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Column 3">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="scrolled"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="scrolled"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cost" HeaderText="Column 4">
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="scrolled"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="scrolled"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**css**

```
    #scrolledGridView
    {
        overflow-x: scroll; 
        text-align: left;
        width: 400px; /* i.e. too small for all the columns */
    }

    .pinned
    {
        position: fixed; /* i.e. not scrolled */
        background-color: White; /* prevent the scrolled columns showing through */
        z-index: 100; /* keep the pinned on top of the scrollables */
    }
    .scrolled
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 150px; /* i.e. col1 Width + col2 width */
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        min-width: 500px; /* set your real column widths here */
    }
    .col1
    {
        left: 0px;
        width: 50px;
    }
    .col2
    {
        left: 50px; /* i.e. col1 Width */
        width: 100px;
    }
```

​

Comment: its working fine, when grid view loads at page load, but when i try to load grid view with any other post back event (ex:- drop down selection or button click) its not working perfect, Although columns are fixed but their Header moves in the right by the number of fixed column. Any solution?

Answer (score 9):

i wrote jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, it can be apply to GridView.
see the image:

[image]

look the website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Supported Browsers

- Internet Explorer 7, 8 (IE 9 Compatibility)
- Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112)
- Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Preview
- Google Chrome(23.0.1271.64 m)
- Mozilla Firefox (16.0.2)
- Apple Safari (5.1.7)

Comment: Your link is not working. :( Can you please provide updated link?

Answer (score 1):

Demo avail Here

http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx

May u miss the script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/gridviewScroll.min.js"></script>
```

That script followed here.

The width for screen size u can modify(44)

Don't Forgot to put the script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function (n) { jQuery.fn.extend({ gridviewScroll: function (t) { function yt(n, t) { pi(n, t), wi(n, t) } function pi(t, i) { t.find("input").each(function () { var t = n(this)[0].type, f, e; if (t == "checkbox" || t == "radio" || t == "text") { var r = n(this)[0].id, u = n(this)[0].name, r = r.replace("_Copy", ""), u = u.replace("_Copy", ""); n(this)[0].name = u + "_" + i, n(this)[0].id = r + "_" + i, f = n("#" + r), e = n(this); switch (t) { case "checkbox": case "radio": e.change(function () { var t = n(this).is(":checked"); f.attr("checked", t) }); break; case "text": e.change(function () { var t = n(this).val(); f.val(t) }) } } }) } function wi(t, i) { t.find("select").each(function () { var t = n(this)[0].id, r = n(this)[0].name, t = t.replace("_Copy", ""), r = r.replace("_Copy", ""), u, f; n(this)[0].name = r + "_" + i, n(this)[0].id = t + "_" + i, u = n("#" + t), f = n(this), f.change(function () { var n = this.selectedIndex; u.prop("selectedIndex", n) }) }) } function bi() { var a = l.attr("id") + "Freeze", o, y, v, h, b, c, k, e, s, d, f, t, g; for (document.getElementById(a) ? it = n("#" + a) : (it = l.clone(), it.attr("id", a), it.css({ position: "absolute", width: "", height: "100%", top: 0, left: 0, zIndex: li }), yt(it, "freezeheader"), it.appendTo(tt)), it.show(), o = it.children().eq(0), o.css({ width: "", height: "100%" }), o.find("td").each(function () { n(this)[0].style.display = "" }), y = o.children().eq(0), ki(), v = w[0].length, f = 0; f < i.headerrowcount; f++) for (t = 0; t < v; t++) (h = w[f][t], h != "RS" && h != "CS") && (b = parseInt(h.split(":")[1]), y.children().eq(f).children().eq(b)[0].style.display = t < ct ? "" : "none"); for (c = r.attr("id") + "Freeze", document.getElementById(c) ? p = n("#" + c) : (p = r.clone(), p.attr("id", c), p.css({ position: "absolute", width: "", top: 0, left: 0, zIndex: li }), yt(p, "freezeitem"), e = p.children().eq(0).children().eq(0), k = e.attr("id") + "Freeze", e.attr("id", k), p.appendTo(u)), e = p.children().eq(0).children().eq(0), e.css({ width: "" }), s = e.children().eq(0), s.find("td").each(function () { n(this)[0].style.display = "" }), d = s.children().length, f = i.headerrowcount; f < d; f++) for (t = 0; t < v; t++) t < ct ? s[0].rows[f].cells[t].style.display = "" : (g = s[0].rows[f].cells[t], g.style.display = "none"); o.width() < i.width - i.railsize ? (it.show(), p.show(), p.height(r.height())) : (it.hide(), p.hide()) } function ki() { var r = 0, n, t; for (ct = 0, n = 0; n < w[0].length; n++) { if (t = w[0][n], t == "RS" || t == "CS") { ct++; continue } if (i.freezesize == r) return ct; r++, ct++ } } function di() { for (var r = a.children().length, u = gi() + 1, t, n = i.headerrowcount; n < r; n++) t = a[0].rows[n].cells[0].children[0], t.style.height = u + "px" } function gi() { for (var e = a.children().eq(i.headerrowcount).children().length, t = 0, f, r, u, n = 0; n < e; n++) f = a.children().eq(i.headerrowcount).children().eq(n), r = f.children().eq(0), r[0].style.height = "auto", u = r[0].offsetHeight, u > t && (t = u); return t } function nr() { var it = f.attr("id") + "VerticalRail", r, ut, l, a, t, p, w, d, tt; document.getElementById(it) ? o = n("#" + it) : (o = n(nt).css({ background: i.railcolor, width: i.railsize + "px", position: "absolute", zIndex: ft }), o.attr("id", it), u.append(o), t = { right: 0 }, o.css(t), o.mousedown(function (t) { clearInterval(e); var i = n(this).offset(), r = t.clientY - i.top + n(document).scrollTop(), u = c.offset().top - i.top, f = c.height() + u; r < u && g(-1, !1, !0), r > f && g(1, !1, !0), e = window.setInterval(function () { var r = t.clientY - i.top + n(document).scrollTop(), u = c.offset().top - i.top, f = c.height() + u; r < u && g(-1, !1, !0), r > f && g(1, !1, !0) }, 200) }), o.mouseup(function () { clearInterval(e) }), o.mouseout(function () { clearInterval(e) })), r = f.attr("id") + "VerticalBar", document.getElementById(r) ? c = n("#" + r) : (c = n(nt).css({ background: i.barcolor, width: i.barsize + "px", position: "absolute", zIndex: ft }), c.attr("id", r), ut = { right: (i.railsize - i.barsize) / 2 }, c.css(ut), u.append(c), c.draggable({ axis: "y", containment: o, start: function () { n(this).css({ backgroundColor: i.barhovercolor }) }, stop: function () { n(this).css({ backgroundColor: i.barcolor }) }, drag: function () { g(0, !1) } })), l = f.attr("id") + "Vertical_TIMG", document.getElementById(l) ? v = n("#" + l) : (v = n(pt).css({ height: i.arrowsize, position: "absolute", zIndex: ft, top: 0 }), v.attr("id", l), v.attr("src", i.varrowtopimg), u.append(v), t = { right: 0 }, v.css(t), v.mousedown(function () { clearInterval(e), g(-1, !1, !0), e = window.setInterval(function () { g(-1, !1, !0) }, 200) }), v.mouseup(function () { clearInterval(e) }), v.mouseout(function () { clearInterval(e) })), a = f.attr("id") + "Vertical_BIMG", document.getElementById(a) ? y = n("#" + a) : (y = n(pt).css({ height: i.arrowsize, position: "absolute", zIndex: ft }), y.attr("id", a), y.attr("src", i.varrowbottomimg), u.append(y), t = { right: 0 }, y.css(t), y.mousedown(function () { clearInterval(e), g(1, !1, !0), e = window.setInterval(function () { g(1, !1, !0) }, 200) }), y.mouseup(function () { clearInterval(e) }), y.mouseout(function () { clearInterval(e) })), p = f.attr("id") + "HorizontalRail", document.getElementById(p) ? s = n("#" + p) : (s = n(nt).css({ background: i.railcolor, height: i.railsize + "px", position: "absolute", zIndex: ft }), s.attr("id", p), u.append(s), s.mousedown(function (t) { clearInterval(e); var i = n(this).offset(), r = t.clientX - i.left + n(document).scrollLeft(), u = h.offset().left - i.left, f = h.width() + u; r < u && rt(-1, !0), r > f && rt(1, !0), e = window.setInterval(function () { var r = t.clientX - i.left + n(document).scrollLeft(), u = h.offset().left - i.left, f = h.width() + u; r < u && rt(-1, !0), r > f && rt(1, !0) }, 200) }), s.mouseup(function () { clearInterval(e) }), s.mouseout(function () { clearInterval(e) })), w = f.attr("id") + "HorizontalBar", document.getElementById(w) ? h = n("#" + w) : (h = n(nt).css({ background: i.barcolor, height: i.barsize + "px", position: "absolute", zIndex: ft }), h.attr("id", w), u.append(h), h.draggable({ axis: "x", containment: s, start: function () { n(this).css({ backgroundColor: i.barhovercolor }) }, stop: function () { n(this).css({ backgroundColor: i.barcolor }) }, drag: function () { rt() } })), d = f.attr("id") + "Horizontal_LIMG", document.getElementById(d) ? b = n("#" + d) : (b = n(pt).css({ width: i.arrowsize, position: "absolute", zIndex: ft, top: 0 }), b.attr("id", d), b.attr("src", i.harrowleftimg), u.append(b), b.mousedown(function () { clearInterval(e), rt(-1, !0), e = window.setInterval(function () { rt(-1, !0) }, 200) }), b.mouseup(function () { clearInterval(e) }), b.mouseout(function () { clearInterval(e) })), tt = f.attr("id") + "Horizontal_RIMG", document.getElementById(tt) ? k = n("#" + tt) : (k = n(pt).css({ width: i.arrowsize, position: "absolute", zIndex: ft }), k.attr("id", tt), k.attr("src", i.harrowrightimg), u.append(k), k.mousedown(function () { clearInterval(e), rt(1, !0), e = window.setInterval(function () { rt(1, !0) }, 200) }), k.mouseup(function () { clearInterval(e) }), k.mouseout(function () { clearInterval(e) })) } function tr() { var n, t; o.css({ height: u.outerHeight() - i.railsize - i.arrowsize * 2, top: i.arrowsize }), c.css({ top: i.arrowsize }), s.css({ width: u.outerWidth() - i.railsize - i.arrowsize * 2, top: u.outerHeight() - i.railsize, left: i.arrowsize }), h.css({ top: u.outerHeight() - (i.railsize + i.barsize) / 2, left: i.arrowsize }), n = Math.max(r.outerHeight() / r[0].scrollHeight * o.outerHeight(), i.minscrollbarsize), c.css({ height: n + "px" }), t = Math.max(r.outerWidth() / r[0].scrollWidth * s.outerWidth(), i.minscrollbarsize), h.css({ width: t + "px" }), n + i.arrowsize * 2 >= r.outerHeight() ? (o.hide(), c.hide(), v.hide(), y.hide(), fi = !0) : (o.show(), c.show(), v.show(), y.show()), t + i.arrowsize * 2 >= r.outerWidth() ? (s.hide(), h.hide(), b.hide(), k.hide()) : (s.show(), h.show(), b.show(), k.show()), o.is(":hidden") && (tt.css({ width: ut }), l.css({ width: ut }), u.css({ width: ut }), r.css({ width: ut }), s.css({ width: ut - i.arrowsize * 2 }), t = Math.max(r.outerWidth() / r[0].scrollWidth * s.outerWidth(), i.minscrollbarsize), h.css({ width: t + "px" }), s.css({ top: u.height() - i.railsize }), h.css({ top: u.height() - (i.railsize + i.barsize) / 2 })), s.is(":hidden") && (o.is(":hidden") ? (u.css({ height: f.height() }), r.css({ height: f.height() })) : (u.css({ height: ot }), r.css({ height: ot })), o.css({ height: ot - i.arrowsize * 2 }), n = Math.max(r.outerHeight() / r[0].scrollHeight * o.outerHeight(), i.minscrollbarsize), c.css({ height: n + "px" })), v.css({ top: 0 }), y.css({ top: o.outerHeight() + i.arrowsize }), b.css({ top: r.outerHeight() }), k.css({ top: r.outerHeight(), left: s.outerWidth() + i.arrowsize }), i.arrowsize == 0 && (v.hide(), y.hide(), b.hide(), k.hide()) } function g(n, t, u) { var f = n, e, s, l; (t || u) && (e = 0, e = t ? n * parseInt(i.wheelstep) / 100 : n, f = parseInt(c.css("top")) + e * (r.outerHeight() / r[0].scrollHeight * o.outerHeight() - 1), s = r.outerHeight() - c.outerHeight() - i.arrowsize, f = Math.min(Math.max(f, i.arrowsize), s), c.css({ top: f + "px" })), l = (parseInt(c.css("top")) - i.arrowsize) / (o.outerHeight() - c.outerHeight()), f = l * (r[0].scrollHeight - r.outerHeight()), r.scrollTop(f), i.freezesize == 0 || h.is(":hidden") || (f + r.outerHeight() > r[0].scrollHeight && (f = r[0].scrollHeight - r.outerHeight()), p.scrollTop(f)) } function rt(n, t) { var u = n, f, e, o; t && (f = n, u = parseInt(h.css("left")) + f * (r.outerWidth() / r[0].scrollWidth * s.outerWidth() - 1), e = r.outerWidth() - h.outerWidth() - i.arrowsize, u = Math.min(Math.max(u, i.arrowsize), e), h.css({ left: u + "px" })), o = (parseInt(h.css("left")) - i.arrowsize) / (s.outerWidth() - h.outerWidth()), u = o * (r[0].scrollWidth - r.outerWidth()), u + l.outerWidth() > l[0].scrollWidth && (u = l[0].scrollWidth - l.outerWidth()), r.scrollLeft(u), l.scrollLeft(u) } function ir() { var u, r, t; if (st.show(), i.headerrowcount > 1) for (t = 1; t < i.headerrowcount; t++) a.children().eq(t).show(); if (lt.find("td").each(function (t) { n(this).children().eq(0).css("width", "auto"), ht.children().eq(t).children().eq(0).css("width", "auto"), n(this).children().eq(0).css("width", "auto") }), u = et.children().eq(0), r = [], lt.find("td").each(function (t) { var i = n(this)[0].childNodes[0].offsetWidth + 1; r[t] = i, n(this).children().eq(0).css({ width: i }) }), rr(), lt.find("td").each(function (n) { for (var s = r[n], f, e, o, t = 0; t < i.headerrowcount; t++) (f = w[t][n], f != "RS" && f != "CS") && (e = f.split(":")[0], e != "N") && (o = f.split(":")[1], u.children().eq(t).children().eq(o).children().eq(0).css({ width: s })) }), st.hide(), i.headerrowcount > 1) for (t = 1; t < i.headerrowcount; t++) a.children().eq(t).hide() } function rr() { for (var n = [], t = 0; t < i.headerrowcount; t++) w[t] = [], n[t] = 0; return lt.find("td").each(function (t) { for (var o, e, f, u, r = 0; r < i.headerrowcount; r++) if (w[r][t] != "RS" && w[r][t] != "CS") { if (o = a.children().eq(r).children().eq(n[r]), n[r]++, e = o.attr("rowspan"), f = o.attr("colspan"), e = e ? parseInt(e) : 1, f = f ? parseInt(f) : 1, e != 1) for (u = r; u < e; u++) w[u][t] = "RS"; if (f != 1) { for (u = 1; u < f; u++) w[r][u + t] = "CS"; w[r][t] = "N:" + (n[r] - 1) } f == 1 && (w[r][t] = "Y:" + (n[r] - 1)) } }), w } function ur() { a.find("td").each(function () { for (var r = n(this)[0].childNodes.length, i, t = 0; t < r; t++) i = n(this)[0].childNodes[t], i.tagName == "DIV" && alert(i.style.position); n(this)[0].innerHTML = "<div>" + n(this)[0].innerHTML + "<\/div>" }) } var i = n.extend({ width: 500, height: 300, railcolor: "#F0F0F0", barcolor: "#CDCDCD", barhovercolor: "#606060", bgcolor: "#F0F0F0", freezesize: 0, arrowsize: 0, varrowtopimg: "", varrowbottomimg: "", harrowleftimg: "", harrowrightimg: "", headerrowcount: 1, railsize: 15, barsize: 15, wheelstep: 20, minscrollbarsize: 30 }, t), e = null, hi = !0, a = null, st = null, lt = null, at = !1, fi = !1, nt = "<div><\/div>", pt = "<img />", tt = null, u = null, l = null, r = null, o = null, c = null, v = null, y = null, s = null, h = null, b = null, k = null, it = null, p = null, et = null, ht = null, f = null, wt = null, d = null, w = [], ci = 0, li = 0, ft = 0, ct = -1, f = n(this), bt, kt, dt, gt, ni, ti, ii, oi, ot, vt, si, vi, ui, yi; if (f[0] && (a = f.children().eq(0), !(a.children().length < 2))) { n.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version == "7.0" || f.css({ position: "relative" }); var ut = i.width, fr = i.height, ei = f.attr("id") + "Wrapper"; if (document.getElementById(ei) ? wt = n("#" + ei) : (wt = n(nt), wt.attr("id", ei), f.parent().wrap(wt)), bt = f.attr("id") + "PanelHeader", document.getElementById(bt) ? tt = n("#" + bt) : (tt = n(nt), tt.attr("id", bt), f.parent().before(tt)), tt.css({ background: i.bgcolor }), kt = f.attr("id") + "PanelItem", document.getElementById(kt) ? u = n("#" + kt) : (u = n(nt), u.attr("id", kt), f.parent().before(u)), u.css({ background: i.bgcolor }), dt = f.attr("id") + "PanelHeaderContent", document.getElementById(dt) ? (l = n("#" + dt), l.scrollLeft(0), l.scrollTop(0)) : (l = n(nt).css({ background: "#FFFFFF" }), l.attr("id", dt), l.appendTo(tt)), gt = f.attr("id") + "PanelItemContent", document.getElementById(gt) ? (r = n("#" + gt), r.scrollLeft(0), r.scrollTop(0)) : (r = n(nt).css({ background: "#FFFFFF" }), r.attr("id", gt), r.appendTo(u), f.parent().appendTo(r)), st = a.children().eq(0), st.attr("id", f.attr("id") + "Header"), lt = a.children().eq(i.headerrowcount), ni = f.attr("id") + "Copy", document.getElementById(ni) ? et = n("#" + ni) : (et = f.clone().children().remove().end(), et.attr("id", ni), et.appendTo(l), ur(), hi = !1), ti = st.attr("id") + "Copy", document.getElementById(ti)) ht = n("#" + ti); else if (ht = st.clone(!1), ht.attr("id", ti), yt(ht, "Copy"), ht.appendTo(et), i.headerrowcount > 1) for (ii = 1; ii < i.headerrowcount; ii++) oi = a.children().eq(ii).clone(!1), yt(oi, "Copy"), oi.appendTo(et); if (ot = fr - tt.height(), vt = f.attr("id") + "PagerBottom", document.getElementById(vt)) d = n("#" + vt), d[0] && d.width(ut); else { var ri = a.children().eq(a.children().length - 1), er = ri.children().eq(0), ai = er.children().eq(0).children().eq(0); ai[0] != null && ai[0].tagName == "TABLE" && (document.getElementById(vt) || (d = n(nt), d.attr("id", vt), d.addClass(ri[0].className), u.after(d), ri.children().eq(0).appendTo(d), d.width(ut)), ri.remove()) } if (d && d[0] && (ot -= d.height()), u.css({ position: "relative", overflow: "hidden", width: ut, height: ot }), r.css({ overflow: "hidden", width: u.outerWidth() - i.railsize, height: ot - i.railsize, zIndex: ci }), tt.css({ position: "relative", overflow: "hidden", width: ut }), l.css({ overflow: "hidden", width: u.outerWidth() - i.railsize, zIndex: ci }), ir(), i.freezesize != 0 && di(), nr(), tr(), i.freezesize == 0 || s.is(":hidden") ? (si = l.attr("id") + "Freeze", vi = r.attr("id") + "Freeze", document.getElementById(si) && (n("#" + si).hide(), n("#" + vi).hide())) : bi(), !hi) return r.hover(function () { at = !0 }, function () { at = !1 }), i.freezesize == 0 || s.is(":hidden") || p.hover(function () { at = !0 }, function () { at = !1 }), ui = function (n) { if (at && !o.is(":hidden")) { var n = n || window.event, t = 0; n.wheelDelta && (t = -n.wheelDelta / 120), n.detail && (t = n.detail / 3), g(t, !0), n.preventDefault && !fi && n.preventDefault(), fi || (n.returnValue = !1) } }, yi = function () { window.addEventListener ? (this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", ui, !1), this.addEventListener("mousewheel", ui, !1)) : document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", ui) }, yi(), this } } }), jQuery.fn.extend({ gridviewScroll: jQuery.fn.gridviewScroll }) })(jQuery)

        var windowSize;

        // Don't try this - $(window).load(function ()
        function pageLoad() {
            windowSize = $(window).width();
            gridviewScroll();
        }

        $(window).resize(function () {
            windowSize = $(window).width();
            gridviewScroll();
        });

        function gridviewScroll() {
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({
                width: windowSize-44,
                height: 500,
                freezesize: 3
            });
        } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Doesn't allow the width to be in % which will mess up the layout :/

Answer (score 0):

Please see this, its also resolved this query that i found.

http://www.bluelemoncode.com/post/2011/12/30/Freezing-gridview-header-and-columns-while-scrolling-rest-of-the-content.aspx

Comment: it has heavy alignment issue!! :(

Answer (score -1):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTaskDataCat1" OnRowCommand="grdTaskDataCat1_RowCommand"
              OnSorting="grdTaskDataCat1_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
              ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowSorting="true" Width="1800px" 
              DataKeyNames="ID" runat="server" 
              OnRowDataBound="grdTaskDataCat1_RowDataBound">
   <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr No" Visible="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" Visible="false" ReadOnly Style="width: 30%" Text='<%# Bind("ID")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <%-- <ItemStyle Width="3%" />--%>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr No" Visible="true" ItemStyle-Width="20px">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNoCat1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
var fixedColumnArray = ["Name","Age"];
foreach (string item in ColumnsToFixed)
{
    fixedColumnArray.push(`<%= item%>`);
} 
if (fixedColumnArray.indexOf("No.") == -1) {
    fixedColumnArray.unshift("No.");
}
var Headers = $('#GridView th')
var ColumnCount = Headers.length;
console.log("GridView")
var TotalWidth = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++) {
    console.log("header", Headers[i])
    var head = $(Headers[i]);
    var headTotalWidth = head.position().left;
    TotalWidth += headTotalWidth;
    console.log("headTotalWidth", headTotalWidth, TotalWidth)
    var headText = head.text().replace(' ', '');
    console.log(head, headText)
    if (fixedColumnArray.indexOf(headText) > -1) {
        head.addClass('hfixed');
        head.css('left', headTotalWidth + 'px');
        var allTd = $(`.SurfaceGrid-class tbody .GridviewScrollItem td:nth-child(${i + 1})`);
        allTd.addClass('fixed');
        allTd.css('left', headTotalWidth + 'px');
    }
}
```