# Create Frozen columns in a ASP.Net Grid View

Tags: asp.net

[image]

I am trying to create a Time sheet for a Employee's in a organization. The System administrator need to populate a list and check whether the time sheet is filled by the employee or not.

I this attached image the first 3 columns EmployeeName, HasLicence and SkillLevel are static. The Columns with date range are dynamic. The columns can vary based on the date range selected. If the date range exceeds page size a horizontal Scroll should appear in the second part and keep the First three columns frozen.

I tried to achieve this by creating 2 separate grid and join together. But i am getting lots of alignment issue. Please suggest me a best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

One possible path is to use CSS to achieve this "frozen" appearance, but it will render differently in older browsers so please test on all browsers you wish to support.

Check out [Freeze asp.net grid view column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529532/freeze-asp-net-grid-view-column) to see one solution to this problem.