# ASP.net Grid Timesheet

Tags: asp.net, gridview

-

Hi Folks,

I am looking to create a TimeSheet entry screen using an editable Grid/GridView in ASP.NET

Just wondering what would be the best way to approach this:

I found this post on stack that shows an image of exactly the type of input I am trying to achieve [Create Frozen columns in a ASP.Net Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655735/create-frozen-columns-in-a-asp-net-grid-view)

Image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgyLc.jpg

I need to create one for a weekly time-sheet entry
Where employees are aligned Vertically and days of week horizontally as headers
Not all values will be filled in

So would the records need to exist in SQL for each employee x days regardless?
or can it be created dynamical and only create/save for days filled in

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the question about the database structure, although it sounds like you're only in the very beginning of your design process.

No, you don't have to have records for every possible date for every employee.  A GridView is based on a sequence of records, but the records don't have to be pulled directly from the database:  in fact, they don't even have be "real" at all.

Assuming you have some kind of `EmployeeWeek` object, you could create a list of empty `EmployeeWeek` objects, one per employee, and bind that to your `GridView`.  You could then use the `GridView` row events to extract the cells that have numbers filled in, and then assemble and save that data.  Thus the records wouldn't exist in the database until after the information had been filled in.

This approach doesn't dictate any particular format for your database tables:  you wouldn't have to save empty days/weeks.  For that matter, you wouldn't have to save the data a week at a time.  You'd have code that would do the hard work of translating the filled-in numbers into the desired record format, and separate code that would persist the records.

Comment: Thanks Ann yes thats correct still in early stages - thats kind of along the lines of what I was thinking, quick question what would be the best way to design the Grid on front-end i'd need something similar to that image shown earlier, with possibility of scrolling week-by-week

thanks

Comment: When you ask "what would be the best way to design the grid" are you asking about usability or coding approaches?

Comment: Thanks for reply, at the time I was asking it was about both design and code, just curious to hear what an other users approach would be......... but the approach I have taken so far is a a gridview with a row per employee and 7 cols for each day of week with a Dropdown in each col for type of day worked - worst thing about gridviews is they are a pain getting access to Controls in templates ..... and to try bind the dropdowns per each employee (basically same dropdown but different bind on different row) is almost impossible

Comment: Maybe you should ask another question about your gridview and the dropdowns?  Maybe there's an easier way to achieve what you want to do.  (And I'm curious as to how you're doing it.)