# How can I freeze the first column of table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to fix the first column a GridView, I looked into some of the related  posts such as:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529532/freeze-asp-net-grid-view-column)

[Link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1120278.aspx?GridView%20Freezing%20First%20Columns%20and%20Freezing%20Column%20s%20Headers)

But could not get it working. Not even [gridviewscroll](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx) helped me. 
May be due  to some conflict with existing css or something.

I am therefore including the rendered HTML table and the CSS, can someone please help me

```css
  .CSSTableGenerator {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:hover td {} .CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator td,
  th {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 7px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000000;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator th {
    background-color: #b2b2b2;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td {
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr td:last-child {
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td {
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #cccccc), color-stop(1, #b2b2b2));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#cccccc", endColorstr="#b2b2b2");
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc, b2b2b2);
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child:hover td {
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #cccccc), color-stop(1, #b2b2b2));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #cccccc 5%, #b2b2b2 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#cccccc", endColorstr="#b2b2b2");
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc, b2b2b2);
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
  }
  .CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
  }
  div#ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_HtmlEditorExtender1_popupDiv.popupDiv {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  textarea {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    resize: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .fieldtextsmallfont {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
  .labeltextsmallfont {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
  }
  .labeltextfont {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .ajax__html_editor_extender_texteditor {
    padding: 5px 8px 2px 15px;
  }
  .gridrow span {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
  }
  .gridheader th {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:700px;overflow-x:scroll;">

  <table class="CSSTableGenerator" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" style="border-width:1px;border-style:Solid;width:100%;">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="gridheader" style="font-weight:bold;">
        <td colspan="1"></td>
        <td colspan="2">(1Q AMJ)</td>
        <td colspan="2">(2Q JAS)</td>
        <td colspan="2">(3Q OND)</td>
        <td colspan="2">(4Q JFM)</td>
        <td colspan="1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridheader" style="font-weight:bold;">
        <th scope="col">Goal / Objective /Target (Provide timeframe by quarter)</th>
        <th scope="col">Goal / Target</th>
        <th scope="col">Results</th>
        <th scope="col">Goal / Target</th>
        <th scope="col">Results</th>
        <th scope="col">Goal / Target</th>
        <th scope="col">Results</th>
        <th scope="col">Goal / Target</th>
        <th scope="col">Results</th>
        <th scope="col">Operation</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridrow">
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblGOT_0">asda</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1goal_0">da</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1result_0">dadad</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2goal_0">ad</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2result_0">ada</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3goal_0">dad</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3result_0">a</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4goal_0">dad</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4result_0">adad</span>
        </td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lbkedit_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$lbkedit','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Edit</a>
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lnkdelete_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$lnkdelete','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridrow">
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblGOT_1">131</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1goal_1">31</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1result_1">313</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2goal_1">1321</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2result_1">131313</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3goal_1">13</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3result_1">313</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4goal_1">1331</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4result_1">1313</span>
        </td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lbkedit_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl04$lbkedit','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Edit</a>
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lnkdelete_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl04$lnkdelete','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridrow">
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblGOT_2">13</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1goal_2">123</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1result_2">1</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2goal_2">313124234</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2result_2"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3goal_2">23423</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3result_2">432424</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4goal_2">242</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4result_2">424</span>
        </td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lbkedit_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl05$lbkedit','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Edit</a>
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lnkdelete_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl05$lnkdelete','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridrow">
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblGOT_3">213333333333</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1goal_3">1111111111111</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1result_3">1111111111111</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2goal_3">11111111111</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2result_3">1111111111111</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3goal_3">111111111111</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3result_3">11111111111</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4goal_3">111111111111</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4result_3">11111111</span>
        </td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lbkedit_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl06$lbkedit','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Edit</a>
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lnkdelete_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl06$lnkdelete','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridrow">
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblGOT_4">rrrrrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1goal_4">ffff</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq1result_4">rrrrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2goal_4">rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq2result_4">rrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3goal_4">rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq3result_4">rrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4goal_4">rrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lblq4result_4">rrrrrrrrrrr</span>
        </td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lbkedit_4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl07$lbkedit','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Edit</a>
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lnkdelete_4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl07$lnkdelete','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Delete</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtGOT" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtGOT"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq1goal" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq1goal"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq1result" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq1result"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq2goal" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq2goal"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq2result" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq2result"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq3goal" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq3goal"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq3result" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq3result"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq4goal" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq4goal"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$ftrtxtq4result" rows="2" cols="20" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ftrtxtq4result"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_lnkadd" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl08$lnkadd','')" style="color:Black;font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">Add</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

I added this.

```
.CSSTableGenerator tr td:first-of-type,   .CSSTableGenerator tr th:first-of-type {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100px;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u4ha0hdc/

Comment: It is close, but not quite exactly what I want. I mean when there is a vertical scroll , the rows positions would mismatch.

Comment: You can see there is an overlapping even when you scroll to the extreme left. Can you fix that? That would be great :)

Comment: So you want row and column headers to stick when you scroll vertically and horizontally?

Comment: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx see the second example.
See how close you can get

Comment: Couldn;t you use that library instead?

Comment: I tried! It didnt work. Actually I am having a GridView, this is the rendered output.

Comment: Can you put them all together in a jsfiddle?

Comment: That would by kind of hard now, but you are quite close, forget the fixed header.. forget the vertical scroll. 
In your code I can not see the second column even when its in default position. Try shifting the first column more to left so second column is visible when page is first loaded

Answer (score 0):

However, to get this behavior for both first row and first column, you need to separate the first row, first column, and first cell from the table, and then continuously set the position of these elements based on the scrolled position of the table body, upon a scroll event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('tbody').scroll(function(e) { 
    $('thead').css("left", -$("tbody").scrollLeft());
    $('thead th:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()-5); 
    $('tbody td:nth-child(1)').css("left", $("tbody").scrollLeft()-5); 
  });
});

body {


 margin: 0;
}
th, td {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white
}
table {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
thead {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: visible;
}
thead th {
  min-width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
}
thead th:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
tbody {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
tbody td {
  min-width: 80px;
}
tbody tr td:nth-child(1) {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```